# Make a key selection and loop function until another key i pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to set up this code to run three functions `c1`, `c2` and `c3` on a keypress and once the selection is made I would like the code to loop indefinitely and keep asking for `input` value until a new key is pressed.

Now the code waits for `keyboard.read_key()` every time and doesn't quite do what I want to do, I understand I have to change the `while` to make it loop on the function rather than the keypress but I also want to stop the function when a different key is pressed.

I am a bit lost.

If anyone could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
import keyboard

grade1 = 10
grade2 = 20
grade3 = 30
grade4 = 40
grade5 = 50
grade6 = 60
grade7 = 70
grade8 = 80
grade9 = 90

def c1():

    print('c1')
    grade = float(input('Select grade: '))

    if grade < grade1:
        print('Grade 0')
    
    elif grade >= grade1 and grade <= grade2:
        print('Grade 1')
              
    elif grade > grade2 and grade <= grade3:
        print('Grade 1')
        
    elif grade > grade3 and grade <= grade4:
        print('Grade 3')
                  
    elif grade > grade4 and grade <= grade5:
        print('Grade 4')
                  
    elif grade > grade5 and grade <= grade6:
        print('Grade 5')
                  
    elif grade > grade6 and grade <= grade7:
        print('Grade 6')
                  
    elif grade > grade7 and grade <= grade8:
        print('Grade 7')
                  
    elif grade > grade8 and grade <= grade9:
        print('Grade 8')

    elif grade > grade9:
        print('Grade 9')

def c2():

    print('c2')
    grade = float(input('Select grade: '))

    if grade < grade1:
        print('Grade 0')
    
    elif grade >= grade1 and grade <= grade2:
        print('Grade 1')
              
    elif grade > grade2 and grade <= grade3:
        print('Grade 1')
        
    elif grade > grade3 and grade <= grade4:
        print('Grade 3')
                  
    elif grade > grade4 and grade <= grade5:
        print('Grade 4')
                  
    elif grade > grade5 and grade <= grade6:
        print('Grade 5')
                  
    elif grade > grade6 and grade <= grade7:
        print('Grade 6')
                  
    elif grade > grade7 and grade <= grade8:
        print('Grade 7')
                  
    elif grade > grade8 and grade <= grade9:
        print('Grade 8')

    elif grade > grade9:
        print('Grade 9')

def c3():

    print('c3')
    grade = float(input('Select grade: '))

    if grade < grade1:
        print('Grade 0')
    
    elif grade >= grade1 and grade <= grade2:
        print('Grade 1')
              
    elif grade > grade2 and grade <= grade3:
        print('Grade 1')
        
    elif grade > grade3 and grade <= grade4:
        print('Grade 3')
                  
    elif grade > grade4 and grade <= grade5:
        print('Grade 4')
                  
    elif grade > grade5 and grade <= grade6:
        print('Grade 5')
                  
    elif grade > grade6 and grade <= grade7:
        print('Grade 6')
                  
    elif grade > grade7 and grade <= grade8:
        print('Grade 7')
                  
    elif grade > grade8 and grade <= grade9:
        print('Grade 8')

    elif grade > grade9:
        print('Grade 9')

def wait():
    keyboard.read_key()

def close():
    quit()

keyboard.add_hotkey('a', c1)
keyboard.add_hotkey('b', c2)
keyboard.add_hotkey('c', c3)
keyboard.add_hotkey('q', close)

while True:
    wait()
```

Comment: 'doesn't quite do what I want to do' - how could we know what you want to do?

Comment: Hi @kosciej16, thanks for your reply, I invite you to read it again as I have mentioned what I need the code to do